# How to sort concatenated array created from 2 AJAX requests by user's search term?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, sorting

I have an input box where a user can type a search term.

```
<input type="text" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search here">
```

Then, I have 2 AJAX requests behind the scenes, "GetMovies" and "GetGames", which return a list of movies and games (respectively) based on the user's search term. When the user types their search term into the input box, the autocomplete suggestions for that box are of similar Movie and Game titles from those AJAX requests.

This is working, but the autocomplete suggestions are not ideally sorted. Currently, the list of matching Games is shown, and then the matching list of Movies is shown underneath the Game list, regardless of if a movie title matches the user's search term much better than any of the Games above it.

So I'm trying to figure out sort the suggestions solely based on how closely they match the user's search term, regardless of the genre. I have one array, `combine` ,  containing the AJAX results from both GetMovies and GetGames, and I've attempted to sort it before displaying it as the Autocomplete suggestions (the commented out section in the code below), but it's causing errors ("Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined", "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined").

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how it may be fixed. Thank you.

```
var results1 = [];
var results2 = [];
var combine = [];

$(".searchbox").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {   
        $.when(GetGames(request), GetMovies(request)
        ).done(function(){
            combine = results2.concat(results1);                  

            /* 
            combine.sort(function(a, b){
                return b[1].indexOf(request.term) - a[1].indexOf(request.term);
            });
            */

            response(combine);    
            }
        )
    }
});

function GetMovies(request) {
    return $.ajax({
        'url': 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + 
                request.term +
                '&type=movie&r=json',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success': function(data) {
            var list = data.Search;

            results1 = $.map(list, function(v,i){
                return {
                    label: v.Title + ' (' + v.Year + ')',
                    value: v.Title
                };
            })
        }
    });
}


function GetGames(request) {              
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/phpscript.php?search=" + request.term, 

        dataType: "xml", 
        success: function(xmlResponse) {                            
            results2 = $("Game", xmlResponse).map(function() {
                return {
                    value: $("GameTitle", this).text() + ", G " + ($.trim($("ReleaseDate", this).text()) || "(unknown date)")
                };
            }).get()                           
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Where does this array come from? Need more details. (I see you deleted all your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays contain objects based on the structure you create in each `map()` .
Those objects have the properties `label` and `value`.

You are looking for `a[1]` and `b[1]` that don't exist...which is why you get undefined

So your sort should be looking at the properties of those objects and comparing the actual values not `indexOf()`

```
combine.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.value.toLowerCase() > a.value.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: forgot to mention in answer to normalize case to optimize sort but should be clear in the code

Comment: This isn't very related, but since you helped before, do you happen to know why this list isn't updating frequently enough? https://jsfiddle.net/7tx6rfwf/3/ For instance, if you type "Eternal" you get a good list, but if you narrow down the search further by adding 'Sunshine' to the query, the suggestions don't change at all.

Comment: suspect api is specific about how spaces are encoded. Check the docs. Is returning "movie not found" in responses which you can inspect in browser dev tools network